# Windows form model and modless dialog form failed to display the text

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a tcp listener in my dashboard form.Whenever the event triggered(approximately occurs every 5 sec) in TCP, the new form needs to be opened along with the text which i have passed through setText. While i performed this one by form.showDialog() the form display the text perfectly. But using form.show() failed to display the text.

Below code works perfectly,

```
PhoneRinging pop_Message = new PhoneRinging();
pop_Message.setText("calling you...");
pop_Message.ShowDialog();
```

but using pop_Message.Show() instead of pop_Message.ShowDialog(); failed to display the text.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: do you mean MessageBox.Show("something");?

Comment: @Sammy, The content which i have passed to the form failed to display it when i use form.show().

Comment: @Os, it is a form not a message box.

Comment: Than your `setText` function is not working. If you want help you must provide infomation. Not working or failed are NO information.